# Parallel processing (lsimulate a program that processes a list of jobs in parallel)

Tags: python, data-structures, priority-queue

**Qns**

You have a program which is parallelized and uses  independent threads to process the given list of 
jobs. Threads take jobs in the order they are given in the input. If there is a free thread, it immediately
takes the next job from the list. If a thread has started processing a job, it doesn’t interrupt or stop
until it finishes processing the job. If several threads try to take jobs from the list simultaneously, the
thread with a smaller index takes the job. For each job you know exactly how long will it take any thread
to process this job, and this time is the same for all the threads. You need to determine for each job
which thread will process it and when will it start processing.
Input Format. The first line of the input contains integers  and .
The second line contains  integers  — the times in seconds it takes any thread to process -th job.
The times are given in the same order as they are in the list from which threads take jobs.
Threads are indexed starting from 0.

**Constraints.** 1 ≤  ≤ 105
; 1 ≤  ≤ 10^5
; 0 ≤  ≤ 10^9.

**Output Format.** Output exactly  lines. -th line (0-based index is used) should contain two space-separated integers — the 0-based index of the thread which will process the -th job and the time
in seconds when it will start processing that job.

**What to do:-**
Think about the sequence of events when one of the threads becomes free (at the start and later after
completing some job). How to apply the priority queue to simulate the processing of these events in the required
order? Remember to consider the case when several threads become free simultaneously.

**Sample Input:**

2 5

1 2 3 4 5

**Output:**

0 0

1 0

0 1

1 2

0 4

**My Approach**

```
from queue import PriorityQueue


nm=input().split()
n=int(nm[0])

q=PriorityQueue()

task=[int(i) for i in input().split()]

ans=[-1 for i in range(len(task))]

for i in range(n):
    q.put((task[i],i))
    ans[i]=[i,0]

for i in range(n,len(task)):
    tmp=q.get()
    threadName=tmp[1]
    time=tmp[0]
    ans[i]=[threadName,time]
    q.put((time+task[i],threadName))
    
for i in ans:
    print(i[0],i[1])
```

I can not able to find any mistake in my code but still not able to pass all the test cases. Please help to find which cases I missed or any bug in my code

Answer (score 1):

I just missing one case where the number of threads is more than or equal to tasks. By considering this I am able to pass all test cases.

**Final Code**

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
nm=input().split()
n=int(nm[0])
m=int(nm[1])

q=PriorityQueue()



task=[int(i) for i in input().split()]

if m<=n:
    for i in range(m):
        print(i,0)
else:

    ans=[-1 for i in range(len(task))]

    for i in range(n):
        q.put((task[i],i))
        ans[i]=[i,0]

    for i in range(n,len(task)):
        tmp=q.get()
        threadName=tmp[1]
        time=tmp[0]
        ans[i]=[threadName,time]
        q.put((time+task[i],threadName))
        
    for i in ans:
        print(i[0],i[1])
```